# Bug? Jquery Mobile Event only fires once using live() and pageshow events

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Trying to use jquery mobile to fire an event (a log in click button) but it only works once.

I have it firing on 'pageshow' event (because of the whole jquery ajax pageload thing, document ready is not applicable) but again it only works on first load, i tried an alert which fires okay. So it must be the .live() event in the $('.check-login'). I am hoping you guys can shed some light on it.

Jquery code:

```
      $('#home').live('pageshow', function(event){
                             alert('home');//fires okay

                             //fires once only
                             $('.check-login').live('click', function() {
                                        var email = $("#email").val();
                                        var password = $("#password").val();
                                        if(email !="" || password !=""){
                                        var datastring = "useremail=" + email + "&userpassword=" + password;                 
                                                              $.ajax({
                                                              type: "POST",
                                                              url: 'http://creativetree.co/creativetreeBeta/mobileImageUpload.php',
                                                              data: datastring,
                                                              success: function(data){
                                                              //success
                                                              $('.check-login').slideUp();
                                                              $('.upload-page').fadeIn();
                                                              $('#userlogin').slideUp();  
                                                              }
                                                              });

                                        }else{
                                        alert('Please fill in all fields');
                                        }
                             });
                             });
```

Comment: By "only fires once", you mean the click event only works the first time it is clicked? Can we see your HTML? If you can provide one, a JSFiddle would help.

Comment: What versions are you using to help people answer the best they can?

Comment: will post again later cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

Go through: [JqueryMobile - Scripting pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Its because when you follow link on your jQuery Mobile site for the same project(internally), the page is loaded with AJAX and only replace body. So, if you want to fire any event on any dom element which is added after page load you need to user .live() function instead of click.  When you traverse through pages its not reload page, its just a internal ajax call from jQuery-Mobile itself.